# TypeError: data.activityDate is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

```
TypeError: data.activityDate is undefined

...s:data.products,psdid:data.psdid});var activityDateString=data.activityDate.spli...
```

plz help me to solve my problem..

```
 var activityDateString = data.activityDate.split("/");
 var activitydate = new Date(activityDateString[2], activityDateString[1] - 1, activityDateString[0]);
 var activityDateTomorrow = new Date();
 var activityDateLastDay = new Date();
 activityDateTomorrow.setTime(activitydate.getTime() + (1000 * 3600 * 24));
 activityDateLastDay = new Date(activitydate.getFullYear(), activitydate.getMonth() + 1, 0);
```

Comment: fnShowEventModal: function (data) {
                    activityDate: data.activityDate,
                    products: data.products,
                    psdid: data.psdid
                });

Comment: Okay..that fact is data.activityDate is undefined. You need to look at your code why the value is undefined. Date calculations are complicated use a reasonable library like momentjs to do date calculations.